# Apply function to entire group in groupby instead of each row in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe consisting of `user_id`, `zip_code` and `text`. I want to remove the values in `text` that is not unique within each (`user_id`,`zip_code`) pair e.g if
(`user_id=2`, `zip_code=123`) has `text= ["hello world"]` and (`user_id=2`, `zip_code=456`)  has `text=["hello foo"]` then I want to remove `"hello"` from both of those sentences.

My thought was to just grouby `["user_id","zip_code"]` and then apply the function to `text` e.g

```py
import pandas as pd

def remove_common_words(sentences: pd.Series):
    all_words= sentences.sum() # Get all the words for each (user,zip) pair

    keep_words = set(common_words[common_words == 1]) # Keep words that only is in one pair
    return sentences.apply(lambda x: set(x)-keep_words)

data.groupby(["user_id","zip_code"])["text"].unique().apply(remove_common_words)
```

the issue is that the function seems to take each value/row for each (user,zipcode) pair and not the entire group i.e `sentences` is not a series but one row thus the first line `all_words = sentences.sum()` does get all the words for the group, but just for each row.

Is there a way to make the input to `apply` be the entire grouped dataframe/series, and operate on that, instead of operating on each row at a time?

Example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "user_id":[1,1,1,2,2,2],
    "zip_code":[123,456,789,111,112,334],
    "text":["hello world","hello foo", "bar foo baz",
              "hello world", "baz boom", "baz foo"]})

def print_values(sentences):
    print(sentences)

data.groupby(["user_id","zip_code"])["text"].unique().apply(print_values)

# ["hello world"]
```

as seen the `print(sentences)` only prints the first row and not the entire group/series like this:

```
0 ["hello world"]
1 ["hello foo"]
2 ["bar foo baz"]
```

Comment: What's the example input and output?

Comment: Editted the question

Comment: `groupby.unique` returns a DataFrame so `groupby.unique.apply(func)` is `DataFrame.apply(func)` which will pass dataframe row. You may want do `groupby.apply(func)` and do unique in the `func`.